# Phalcon CLI task name

Tags: php, phalcon

I have folder tasks with MainTask.php and SomeOtherTask.php files...

**How can I run only the SomeOtherTask?**

To run the main task I only need to write

> php cli.php

, but I want some serious file name and not MainTask...

Here is my other task:

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Cli\Task;

class DeleteExpiredAuthTokens extends Task{

    public function mainAction()
    {
        echo "Hello world war Z";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried php cli.php SomeOther but is not working (SomeOther wihtout the suffix Task)

Comment: And you sure that your task have mainAction?

Comment: +Juri I've pasted the task..please see the edited post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Directory set-up**

You will need to create a `tasks/` directory in `app/`, then you can make appropriate file names; for example;

```
app/
├── tasks/
│   ├── SomeTask.php
│   ├── SomeOtherTask.php
│
├── cli.php
```

Now, you'd need to create a `cli.php` file, which your command line will call. In here, you'd need to look at the call arguments and pass it in your `$console->handle()` method. For example;

**cli.php**

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault\Cli as CliDI;
use Phalcon\Cli\Console as ConsoleApp;
use Phalcon\Loader;


// Using the CLI factory default services container
$di = new CliDI();

$arrBasePath = preg_split("/\//", __DIR__);
$limit = sizeof($arrBasePath);

$strBasePath = "";
for ($count = 0; $count < $limit - 1; $count++) {
    $strBasePath .= $arrBasePath[$count] . '/';
}

define('BASE_PATH', $strBasePath);

/**
 * Register the autoloader and tell it to register the tasks directory
 */
$loader = new Loader();

$loader->registerDirs(
    [
        __DIR__ . "/tasks",
        __DIR__ . "/models",
        __DIR__ . "/controllers"
    ]
);

$loader->register();

// Create a console application
$console = new ConsoleApp();
$console->setDI($di);

//Process the console arguments
$arguments = [];
foreach ($argv as $k => $arg) {
    if ($k == 1) {
        $arguments["task"] = $arg;
    } elseif ($k == 2) {
        $arguments["action"] = $arg;
    } elseif ($k >= 3) {
        $arguments["params"][] = $arg;
    }
}

try {
    // Handle incoming arguments
    $console->handle($arguments);
} catch (\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit(255);
}
```

Now, say in `app/tasks/SomeTask.php` you have the following;

**app/tasks/SomeTask.php**

```
use Phalcon\Cli\Task;

class SomeTask extends Task
{

    public function MainAction()
    {
        echo "This is the main action\r\n";
    }

    public function OtherAction()
    {
        echo "This is other action\r\n";
    }

}
```

You can just call your tasks by passing them in the arguments, for example;

```
$ php cli.php some
This is the main action
```

Or, call the other method by passing it;

```
$ php cli.php some other
This is other action
```

**Notes**

- Your class name needs to end in `Task`. When calling this class, you omit it. See how I called the `someTask` class.
- In your example, rename `DeleteExpiredAuthTokens` to become `DeleteExpiredAuthTokensTask` otherwise you'll get the following error message: `DeleteExpiredAuthTokensTask handler class cannot be loaded`